# Need help Splitting a string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string which is being returned by a server and I need to get some information from it. This is the string:

(stock-info (msg-id 57) (reply-to 4) (ref "IC00000000234" std) (total (boxes 61)) (valid (boxes 61)) )

I need to get the total number of boxes and the valid boxes and put them into parameters. Ive tried using substrings and splitting the string into different parts, the problem is that this string could be different lengths so it dosent alway bring back the right result. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem:

```
        Dim MyString As String = "(stock-info (msg-id 57) (reply-to 4) (ref ""IC00000000234"" std) (total (boxes 61)) (valid (boxes 61)) )"
    Dim SringExtracted As String = ""
    Dim MyKey As String = ""

    'Total Boxes
    MyKey = "(total (boxes"
    SringExtracted = MyString.Substring(MyString.LastIndexOf(MyKey) + MyKey.Length)
    SringExtracted = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(SringExtracted, SringExtracted.IndexOf("))"))
    Dim TotalBoxes As Integer = Val(SringExtracted)

    'Valid Boxes
    MyKey = "valid (boxes"
    SringExtracted = MyString.Substring(MyString.LastIndexOf(MyKey) + MyKey.Length)
    SringExtracted = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(SringExtracted, SringExtracted.IndexOf("))"))
    Dim ValidBoxes As Integer = Val(SringExtracted)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I see now why I couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of problem where a *regular expression* can be useful:

```
Option Infer On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim s = "(stock-info (msg-id 57) (reply-to 4) (ref ""IC00000000234"" std) (total (boxes 61)) (valid (boxes 48)) )"

        Dim reTotal As New Regex("total \(boxes ([0-9]+)")
        Dim reValids As New Regex("valid \(boxes ([0-9]+)")

        ' initialise with a value than cannot appear in the string
        ' so it can be checked for later if needed
        Dim totalBoxes As Integer = -1
        Dim validBoxes As Integer = -1

        If reTotal.IsMatch(s) Then
            totalBoxes = CInt(reTotal.Match(s).Groups(1).Value)
        End If

        If reValids.IsMatch(s) Then
            validBoxes = CInt(reValids.Match(s).Groups(1).Value)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine($"Total: {totalBoxes} Valid: {validBoxes}")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> Total: 61 Valid: 48

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Splits the string by "boxes ", ignores the first part of the string, and then strips out all non-numeric characters for the remaining two strings (in char array form) before converting them back to a string. If you want them as integer just parse them afterwards.

```
Dim myString = "(stock-info (msg-id 57) (reply-to 4) (ref 'IC00000000234' std) (total (boxes 61)) (valid (boxes 61)) )"

Dim splitArray = myString.Split("boxes ").Skip(1)

Dim totalBoxesAsString = New String(splitArray.First.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
Dim validBoxesAsString = New String(splitArray.Last.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions for this situation.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input As String = "(stock-info (msg-id 57) (reply-to 4) (ref ""IC00000000234"" std) (total (boxes 60)) (valid (boxes 61)) )"
For Each match As Match In Regex.Matches(input, "\(total \(boxes (\d+)\).+\(valid \(boxes (\d+)\)")
    Console.WriteLine("Total={0}, Valid={1}", match.Groups.Item(1).Value, match.Groups.Item(2).Value)
Next
```